# Authenticate against WSO2 Identity Server with no browser and get SAML2 assertion message

Tags: wso2, saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to setup a service provider that uses WSO2 IS for authentication via SAML2. Now, wehave a use-case in which the user is a machine (i.e. an external program) that needs to access the service provider. Since the user is a machine, there is no browser and cannot use the WSO2 login form to complete the authentication steps, though it has been given a username and password since it is still a user.

**My question is how can this non-GUI user participate in the SAML2 workflow (specifically pass credentials to WSO2 to obtain a SAMLV2 Assertion message) and access the service provider?**

I tried to do the following as a simulation but I failed

```
1) curl -v -k http://localhost:8000/service_provider/login
2) Extracting the SAML message from the response:
    curl --user username:password -v  -k https://localhost:9443/samlsso?SAMLRequest=<ENCODED_REQUEST>
```

Basically, I was expecting to get a redirect response from WSO2 back to the service provider with SAML assertion message, but instead I got the following:
        https://localhost:9443/authenticationendpoint/login.do;jsessionid=7QON18982323HWIH?commonAuthCallerPath=%2Fsamlsso&forceAuth=false&passiveAuth=false&tenantDomain=carbon.super&sessionDataKey=122JhQ-JQOJ-H8123&relyingParty=test-saml2&type=samlsso&sp=test&isSaaSApp=false&authenticators=BasicAuthenticator:LOCAL, which is the same url that is used when a human user authenticates using a browser.

I also tried using HTTP-POST Binding with "sectoken" form param as suggested in this article: http://xacmlinfo.org/2015/02/12/sso-without-identity-provider-login-page/ . But it didn't work either.

I also tried making SOAP requests to WSO2's AuthenticationAdminHttpsSoap12Endpoint service, specifically the "login" method. I used the JSESSIONID I got from the SOAP response to the above steps but the effect was the same. This is not a surprise to me since WSO2 does not use JSESSIONID to check if you are authenticated already (at least not for trying to grab SAML responses).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get login form

Request: `curl -v  http://localhost:8000/service_provider/login`

From the response, extract `SAMLRequest` and `SSOAuthSessionID` (if `RelayState` is present extract it too)

2. Send SAML request to IDP using extracted values in step 1 (In browser this will happen through redirection)

Request Endpoint : `https://<is_host>:9443/samlsso`

```
Verb :post
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Parameters:[
SAMLRequest:<value from previous step>,
SSOAuthSessionID:<value from previous step>,
RelayState :<value from previous step>]
```

The response will give IS login page. Extract `sessionDataKey` from that.

3. Login by providing user name and password

Reqeust Endpoint: `https://<is_host>:9443/commonauth`

```
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Verb :post
Parameters: [tocommonauth:true,username:xxxx,password:xxx,sessionDataKey:<extracted from previous step>]
```

Extract the SAMLResponse from the response

5. Post the SAML response to the ACS url of service provider